# Get amazon mws usertoken and call mws api

Tags: oauth, amazon-mws

I'm trying to a build a web application for Amazon sellers. I don't understand how to call Amazon MWS API using `oauth` calling and get user MWS authtoken like Etsy API.

1. User Clicks Link
2. User Signs In
3. IRP Presents the Agreement
4. Once Agreed, the key is returned to the MWS token

I've seen several programs do this but I can't find it. There seems to be no documentation on this topic and nobody is talking about it.

How can we implemented IRP?

Comment: Please read this before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In order to get good answers is important to show what you have tried and what errors do you get and be very precise in your questions. General problems are difficult to simulate and not accepted on SO.

Comment: i have completed my api but this api only single user but i want multi user like etsy

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the API to be multiuser, but this is something that you should communicate with MWS not on Stackoverflow. There is little we can do to help you implement a desired API feature for a private company API.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Ruby on Rails library for that: https://github.com/machineboy2045/omniauth-amazon-mws

If you use other languages, you can translate that library and make your own library for your programming language.

Comment: That rails library is for interacting with the "Login with Amazon" services, which only allows pulling profile data and not the full MWS API.

Answer (score -2):

Here you can find the documentation for Amazon API:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html

and here you can download there code libraries, there is a cool PHP code included:

https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/146-6096878-3812927?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest